# Return multiple resultset from a function in postgres using cursor

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, pgadmin-4, ref-cursor

I want to write a function in postgres which will return multiple resultset from different tables. I found that we can achieve that using ref cursors. So i created one function supposed to return 2 results from different tables. When I call the cursors under a transaction , no results are returned. It just says query executed successfully. Postgres version --> 14.X. I am running this query in pgadmin 4.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION multipleresultset()
RETURNS SETOF refcursor AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
ref1 refcursor := 'cursor1';
ref2 refcursor := 'cursor2';
BEGIN
open ref1 FOR
SELECT * FROM table1;
RETURN NEXT ref1;

open ref2 FOR
SELECT * FROM table2;
RETURN NEXT ref2;
--RETURN;
END;$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

begin;
select * from multipleresultset();
FETCH ALL in "cursor1";
FETCH ALL in "cursor2";
commit;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This SQL code is fine by itself, but your SQL client is probably sending the whole block in one go as a multi-query string. Then if shows only the result of the last instruction of that sequence, which is the result of `commit`.

If you tried this in in `psql` (the primary command-line interface for postgresql), it would show results, since `psql` parses the SQL buffer to identify queries between `;` and sends them as separate statements (use `\;` to group them).

Comment: Correct. I ran the commands separately and was able to view the result in pgadmin